# Flutter Web- Catch block of Try/Catch not firing on iPad ( ok on PC)

Tags: flutter, dart

I am Using Flutter 3.13.7/Dart   in Web App all works except one strange issue that seems to be platform specific between PC  or iPad.

I am triggering an AlertDialog.
It works on a PC running Chrome and the AlertDialog shows as expected.
On an iPad ( using Safari, or Chrome) the AlertDialog never shows.

I am setting a variable gatewayDetected in Provider.

The AlertDialog visibility is triggered by gatewayDetected when = 'fail'

It really appears that the iOs is not responding to  the Catch{} block as expected.

```
// HDLAN RX Status
class HdlanRxStatus extends ChangeNotifier {
  List  RxSnmpStatus = List.filled(48, '1');
  List RxChSelect = List.filled(48, 'Search');
  List sourceList = ['Cable1','Cable2','Cable3','Cable4','Cable5','Cable6'];
  int poeStatus = 1;  // PoE wattage
  String switchIPAddress = '';
  String gatewayDetected = 'ok';
  String ciscoSwitchDetected = '';
  getSnmpStatus() async {

    getSnmpStatus() async {
    //
    try{
      print("http://${html.window.location.hostname.toString()}:1880/ciscoStat");
      var response = await http.get(Uri.parse("http://${html.window.location.hostname.toString()}:1880/ciscoStat"));
      print(response.body);
      switchIPAddress = jsonDecode(response.body)["SwitchIPAddress"];
      RxSnmpStatus = jsonDecode(response.body)["PortVlanMembership"];
      // Update RX with Input Source Name
      RxSnmpStatus.asMap().forEach((index, item) => {
            RxChSelect[index] = sourceList[RxSnmpStatus[index]-2]
        });
      poeStatus = jsonDecode(response.body)["PoE"];
      ciscoSwitchDetected = jsonDecode(response.body)["PS1Stat"]; // 'OK' or 'link loss'
      gatewayDetected = 'ok';

    }on Exception catch (e) {
          print(e); // Only catches an exception of type `Exception`.
         gatewayDetected = 'fail';
    } catch(error){

    }finally{
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  }
```

I have tested the app simultaneously on 2 devices ( a PC, and an iPad) side by side.
The PC with Chrome = works.
ipad ( with Safari or Chrome ) = does not work.

Comment: Are you sure that an exception is being thrown?  If so, what is the exception, and what is throwing it?

Comment: I am sure the catch(error) is thrown. I ran the Web App simultaneously , one on PC(Chrome) and the other on iPad( Safari , Chrome). The Web App on the PC showed the AlertDialog that is triggered from the catch(error). But the iPad never showed the AlertDialog.

Comment: Again: what is the exception you expect, and what is supposed to be throwing it?

Comment: I am expecting an 'XMLHttpRequest error.'  I am simulating a failure of an local http server. In the case the server is not connected/failed, the user should get an alert. I have also tried an 'on Exception'   . Once again, the Chrome on the PC works , but iPad ( Safari, Chrome) the exception is never fired therfore the AlertDialog is never shown.